# How do we provide better answers? Specifically, with visuals

Tags: discussion

*This may not be the right place for this*

I have seen a variety of posts using incredibly well done visuals to help convey concepts. As a large number of our responses revolve around proximity, placement, shape, size, etc. I think it would be beneficial to have a list of tools that help create these visuals, the scenarios they're best for, as well as their strengths and weaknesses.

Maybe not *just* for answers, but for questions as well. Would it be worth adding a guide to the wiki with this sort of information?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean here, do you mean a guide for using the Balsamiq Mockups tool to help, or a list of tools like that to make quick mockup screenshots to post on here?

Comment: I was thinking a guide around how visuals can be used to enhance an answer, the kind of software that can be used to produce those visuals, and brief pros/cons of the listed software.